# wordpress youtube something like a slideshow

Tags: wordpress, video

I have a wordpress site with categories containing youtube videos. So for example i have a category cinema and when you click it you see a sticky post with the youtube video on top and afterwards the titles of the rest of the youtube videos i have for this category. When i click one of the titles the single.php is loaded and i see the youtube video.

My question is: how do I edit the code so in the category-cinema.php when i click one of the titles the video is loaded there without loading the single.php file?

Answer (score 1):

if clicking on a link does not jump to a page, I think you need to use Javascript to accomplish that. then you can go to the archive.php and modify the title link(something like below) inside the loop. :

```
 <h1 class="artitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a></h1>
```